# unable to resolve MappingNotFoundException :resource:/login.hbm.xml not found in hibernate

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I've been messing around this first hibernate from last few days, after solving going through multiple SO threads

[org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: *hbm.xml not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127608/org-hibernate-mappingnotfoundexception-resource-hbm-xml-not-found)

[org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834131/org-hibernate-mappingnotfoundexception)

[org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: *hbm.xml not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127608/org-hibernate-mappingnotfoundexception-resource-hbm-xml-not-found)

i am still unable to figure out how to deal with this

here is my **'hibernate.cfg.xml'**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">cijagani</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.101/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">cijagani</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <mapping resource="/login.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

->Along with this **login.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jun 28, 2014 6:39:37 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="login" table="LOGIN">
        <id name="username" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="USERNAME" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="password" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PASSWORD" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

->along with log output

```
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: /login.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: /login.hbm.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:738)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2195)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2147)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2100)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2015)
    at StoreData.main(StoreData.java:14)
```

->StoreData.java is as below

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class StoreData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        //creating configuration object  
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();  
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");//populates the data of the configuration file  

        //creating seession factory object  
        SessionFactory factory= new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();  

        //creating session object  
        Session session=factory.openSession();  

        //creating transaction object  
        Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();  

        login e1=new login();  
        e1.setUsername("vi");  
        e1.setPassword("8434");  

        session.persist(e1);//persisting the object  

        session.getTransaction().commit();//transaction is committed  
        session.close();  

        System.out.println("successfully saved");  

    }  
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure with hbm file path `/login.hbm.xml`? can show your project directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

this is the basic steps that need to be followed while developing hibernate application ( am telling you from the basic level)

### Steps To Create Hibernate Prog

1. Create Project
2. Create package inside the project **(This is what I think You have missed (it is mandatory) - Ex**: **package in.myproject.test)**
3. Create POJO Classes, configuration and hbm files
4. And at last, write your Java application

Remember

Creating package is must

**cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");** -- we supply configure method, the configuration file name when we give our own name to the configuration file ( Ex - "myConfiguration.cfg.xml" (or) "myConfig.xml" etc).

Even if you supply the default configuration file name i.e "hibernate.cfg.xml", still it is fine (but  not recomended)

Answer (score 0):

simply there was error in this

```
 <mapping resource="/login.hbm.xml"></mapping>
```

i just converted it to this

```
<mapping resource="login.hbm.xml"></mapping>
```

and it worked,besides this there were minor errors in field name property of login.hbm.xml which i sorted out by simply changing the names as they were on mysql table name.